# How to create a <ul> with a triangle for the :active row?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I know my title is not the best but I tried as best I could. It's a little hard for me to explain my problem, but what I want is to create a horizonal list that has a "triangle" in the active element. I show an image below.
[image: Example]

It this possible with CSS? I know how I would do with jQuery but I want to use CSS now and no jQuery/Javascript.

I have actually created a fiddle which you can find a link to below: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jackbillstrom/3dNcj/

I tried a javacript solution but wasn't satisfied with it because I would like to use CSS instead. My goal is to have that triangle as you can see in the example to "ease" between which `<li>` you click. Is this even possible or am I dreaming?

Comment: The example doesn't seem to have a JS implementation. Is this intentional?

Comment: @Asad Yes, because I want to give it a shot with pure CSS

Comment: You could try the vintage technic by using a small picture as a background. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7073558/1009061 for a CSS3 implementation.

Comment: Would be perfect if I didn't want that "ease" effect :/

Comment: @Jack Can you please elaborate on why you don't want to use JS?

Comment: @Asad I don't believe in JS...Not just kidding, I want to push this project to the limit with as little JS as possible :)

Comment: Well, you're going to find yourself jumping through a lot of hoops, because there is only so much that can be accomplished with declarative layout. Having the freedom of imperative control over layout that JS provides will let you get things done with very little effort, but I guess if this is just on a whim/principle there isn't much I can say to change your mind.

Comment: @Asad That comment, did in fact change my mind.. But it would still be something if we could get the answer to the CSS option :)

Comment: @Jack updated my answer to support pure css3 transitions, have a look, some js will be involved :)

Comment: @Jack brentonstrine has managed to come up with an answer that uses no JS at all, which is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just add this to the bottom of your CSS:

```
ul#objects li {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
ul#objects li.active:after, ul#objects li:hover:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #666;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top:5px;
    right: -8px;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/3dNcj/3/). No jQuery and you even get the hover effect for free.

**Update 1**: Here I used `:target` so that the arrow only shows up when you click on the element: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/3dNcj/10/).

**Update 2**: Got it. CSS only solution where the arrow slides to follow the one you click on: [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/3dNcj/11/).

**Update 3**: And here it is updated so that the arrow slides when you hover as well as when you click. Hopefully you can see in the code that the clicking effect requires the `:target` code as well as the addition of the links in your HTML, but if you only want to do it with the `:hover` effect and then switch to the different page, you don't need the links I added to your HTML, you just need to add the `.active` class into the CSS where I have `:target`. Hopefully that makes sense. ***[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/3dNcj/12/)***.

Comment: Brilliant answer +1 for `:target`.

Comment: You could also use radio buttons instead of `:target` to be prevent interference with other fragment identifiers on the page.

Comment: This is great, the only thing missing is that "easing" effect. No problem for me though! :)

Comment: @Jack It does have the easing effect, or at least it does in my browser. What are you looking for, specifically?

Comment: I think that I've might misslead you. This is what I meant with "easing effect" http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/3dNcj/2/

Comment: I'm not seeing what that does that http://jsfiddle.net/brentonstrine/3dNcj/12/ doesn't.

Comment: Why have you used `-webkit-transform` and not also included the standard `transform`

Comment: Ah, that was a mistake. It should just be `transform`: the days of vendor-prefixes are gone. Thanks for pointing that out. I edited it.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

Some basic CSS to create the triangle,

```
.triangle{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 

    border-right:10px solid white; 
    position: absolute;
    right: -1px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

A simple js using the `.animate()` to move the pointer,

```
$("li").click(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $(".triangle").animate({
        top: $this.position().top + "px"
    });
});
```

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/3dNcj/2/)

**UPDATE**

Using CSS3 transitions on browsers that support it, a bit of `JS` required to re-insert elements to restart the animations.

Brentonstrine has a better Pure CSS3 solution.

[Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/3dNcj/9/)

Comment: That is exactly what I want, but, isn't there a way with only CSS?

Comment: Let me try, give me some time :) only CSS(3) would not be supported on lower browsers btw.

Comment: @Jack I think Jack you should have all versions: background, CSS3 and Javascript. You fall back from CSS3 > JS > Image

Comment: Looks like we have a winner! I found this very hopeful and I think others will find this useful as well :D Cheers!

Comment: This isn't pure CSS3 at all. You're still using JS to slide the thing around. That said, I think JS is the only approach here.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it, this solution still uses JS. My solution is indeed pure CSS.

Comment: @Asad and brentonstrine check this, http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/3dNcj/13/, I've mentioned in a comment above that some JS will be used, in this case, just to re-insert the element, so the css animation restarts. It uses pure CSS3 to animate the `.triangle` however. Also, using a fallback for browsers that don't support css3 animations

Comment: @badZoke, your solution doesn't work at all without Javascript, as far as I can tell. I deleted the JS from your example and it doesn't work.

Comment: @brentonstrine it won't, that's what I've mentioned in my comment, my solution uses a bit of JS

Comment: It's just confusing because you said "Using pure css3 on browsers that support it."

Comment: @badZoke "Pure CSS" and "uses a bit of JS" are mutually exclusive. brentonstrine's is the correct answer here.

Comment: Updated my answer to fix the ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks for clearing the ambiguity. For the record, @badZoke's solution, while not "pure CSS", may still be a better solution for some people, since my solution depends on advanced CSS3 things that older browsers won't support. I'm an advocate of "graceful degradation"/"progressive enhancement" though, so basically, if people want to use old browsers, they can still use the website (no functionality is broken) but they don't get the full experience.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way to accomplish this with pseudoelements. This uses pure CSS, but relies on CSS 3:

```
#objects > li:hover:after{
    content: ' ';
    border-color: transparent #fff transparent transparent;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 10px;
}
#objects > li:hover{
    position:relative;
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wFege/

I've been racking my brains for a bit, but unfortunately can't think of any way to make this incorporate the "sliding" effect in badZoke's answer. Would you care to elaborate on why you can't use JS? If the problem is merely not wanting to include jQuery, you can accomplish the same thing with native JS.

Answer (score 1):

`Asad`'s pure CSS solution is really good. I did a similar thing which makes a horizontal list (which you mentioned).

http://jsfiddle.net/teAPW/

```
ul, li {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #AAA;
    border-left:none;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100px;
    background:#DDD;
    color:#999;
    position:relative;
}
ul > li:first-child { border-left:1px solid #AAA; }
ul > li.active { border-right:none; }
ul > li.active + li { margin-left:10px; border-left:1px solid #AAA }
ul > li.active:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    right:0;
    border:13px solid;
    border-color:transparent #FFF transparent transparent;
    content:"";
}
```